# How to instantiate specific value of a double array

Tags: java, arrays, instantiation

I'm trying to instantiate double arrays in the main class. I need to do this with 3 different configuration:

1) with complete double arrays like (String[][], String[][])

2) with one specific value and one with double array like (String[][], String[1][])

3) with two specific values like (String[1][], String[1][])

In my code I have developed two classes, the **predicate** and the **main** class(where I instantiate the arrays)

The predicate class is

```
public class Predicate {

//objects
private static String[] airport = {"cdg","lhr"};
private static String[] loc = {"south","north"};
private static String[] city = {"paris","london"};
private static String[] pack = {"p1","p2"};
private static String[] vehicle = {"plane","truck"};

//types
private static String[][] place = {airport, loc, city};
private static String[][] physobj = {pack, vehicle};


List<String[][]> parameters = Arrays.asList(place, physobj);

public Predicate(String[][] p, String[][] p1 ) {

    p = this.place;
    p1 = this.physobj;

}

}
```

The main class is

```
public class Main {

//objects
private static String[] airport = {"cdg","lhr"};
private static String[] loc = {"south","north"};
private static String[] city = {"paris","london"};
private static String[] pack = {"p1","p2"};
private static String[] vehicle = {"plane","truck"};


//types
private static String[][] place = {airport, loc, city};
private static String[][] physobj = {pack, vehicle};


//HERE I TRY TO INSTANTIATE
Predicate in_city = new Predicate(place, place); // HERE I WANT (String[][], String[x][]), OTHERWISE 
//SELECTING ONLY THE CITY ARRAY

Predicate at = new Predicate(physobj, place); // THIS IS (String[][], String[][]) and works

Predicate in = new Predicate(physobj, physobj); // HERE I WANT (String[x][], String[x][]), OTHERWISE SELECTING ONLY PACK AND VEHICLE ARRAYS
```

}

I have tried to make like

```
Predicate in = new Predicate(physobj[1][], physobj[1][]);
```

and I receive this error

```
  - Syntax error on token "[", Expression expected after 
   this token
  - Syntax error on token "[", Expression expected after 
   this token
```

How can I select specific values of the double arrays for the instantiation?

Comment: That constructor for Predicate doesn't look right. Why are you assigning your arguments which you pass in, to the class variables?

Comment: Is that the problem for selecting the arrays specific values?